# Does child class serialize parent class' members that are not serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

If class B extends class A, class B implements Serializable, and class A has a public non-static initialized variable that is not serializable... trying to write a class' B object with writeObject() method of FileOutputStream, will serialize the non-serializable inherited member from A for writing it in the file with the rest of the variables of class B or it will throw NotSerializableException? I've tried it, and it works, but I don't know why... So I'm not sure if it always works, or I'm missing something... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will serialize the object `B`, but not the properties of object `A`. So if you had class structure like

```
static class Parent {
    int x = 1;
}
static class Child extends Parent implements Serializable {
    int y = 2;
}
```

And then create new `Child` instance, serialize/deserialize

```
Child c = new Child();
c.x = 10;
c.y = 20;
// ... serialize/deserialize
c = (Child) ois.readObject();
System.out.println(c.x); // prints 1, not 10!
System.out.println(c.y); // prints 20
```

Comment: It actually prints 0, not 1 or 10. Try it.

Answer (score -2):

No. in order for a child class to be serializable, the parent has to be serializable as well.

If the parent class is in your codebase, you can exclude fields from serializing with the 'transient' keyword

Comment: If the parent class isn't serializable it isn't serialized. Otherwise seriaization woud not work at all, because `java.lang.Object` isn't Serializable. Answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: Parent class need not be serializable for a child class to be serializable.